# "None" in legend pandas python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, legend

I am using WinPython Notebook with Python 2.7.
So I am reading several DataFrames like this:

```
run[y2][y3][x] = pd.read_excel(xls_file, x)
```

When then I use:

```
run[y2][y3][x].plot()
```

I get nice plot with 3 lines and  a legend describing these lines as it is in the excel file on the top of the column.

However, when I plot it like this:

```
run[case]['fluent'][var].plot(x = 'r', y = 'inlet')
```

What I get in the legend is "None" only. Even when I use `label = 'inlet'` in the .plot() part.

http://postimg.org/image/l4akauycz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsm')
df.set_index(keys= ['index_col'], inplace=True)
df['col_to_plot'].plot(legend = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in pandas, and will be fixed in the upcoming 0.16.1 release (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9574).

A possible workaround for now is to supply the `y` column as a list:

```
df.plot(x='r', y=['inlet'])
```

Comment: On a side note now, is there anyway to make pandas use text from `label = 'inlet experimnet' ` and print it in Legend?

Comment: yes, you normally can use `label='inlet experiment'`, but that was also part of the bug in 0.15 and 0.16 ... (and will also be fixed in 0.16.1). So in that case, maybe you can better use the other answer's alternative.